# Book I read in the mid 90s about an alien invasion on one of two domes

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

I don't remember much other than the humans build two domes. One was where they were mining for something. The other was for protection. The end of the book centres around a big alien attack on the dome and the presumption is it's the one the humans are in but the aliens attack the wrong dome.

---

The last time I posted this question (or a [different forum](https://www.boards.ie/discussion/2056924942/cant-remember-book-title-or-author-help), several years ago) I apparently recalled some details not mentioned above.

> I think one was in London (which was the important one) and one was over a mine or something, in South America

Comment: "*Around the mid 90s I read a sci-fi book about an alien invasion. I don't remember a whole lot about it other than somehow mankind had built two massive domes, I think one was in London (which was the important one) and one was over a mine or something, in South America. Basically towards the end the aliens attacked the wrong dome and somehow this led to us winning the fight (helpful I know).*" - https://www.boards.ie/discussion/2056924942/cant-remember-book-title-or-author-help

Comment: Welcome, please, if you think of anything else that may help us to help you, add it to the text of your question.  Was it a long novel, or short story for instance?  Was there a description of the aliens that has stuck with you?  Was the story set on Earth or another planet?

Comment: Yes that was me asking the same question 10 years ago! I didn't even remember it was in London this time.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  It was based on earth. Honestly I don't remember anything else other than I really enjoyed it.

Answer (score -2):

This made me think of the ending of Joe Haldeman's *The Forever War* (1974). I Not a great answer, but maybe it will inspire somebody else

Comment: And I think it will inspire me to reread *The Forever War*.

Comment: Can you explain how this matches the question asked?

Comment: I see now that it was a crappy answer. It took me a while to get around to rereading *The Forever War* (still an excellent book, so that was a win). I had thought that in the last section of the book there were two domes ... and there was only one.